# autofocus attribute not working in Firefox on display state change

Tags: javascript, jquery, autofocus

I'm trying to add auto focus to a form. I have it working in Chrome but cannot get it working in Firefox with the below code. I think the reason could potentially be that it needs to be just `autofocus` rather than `autofocus="autofocus"`. Would I be correct in assuming this? If so is there some way I can add it? I'm using a framework called SilverStripe and don't have direct access to editing the input field as it's done dynamically so would need to do it via JavaScript most likely.

```
<input type="text" name="Search" class="form-control search-form" id="TemplateSearchForm_SearchForm_Search" placeholder="Search..." autofocus="autofocus">
```

Note I am initially hiding the input box and displaying on the click of an icon by adding a class:

```
jQuery('.search').click(function () {
    if(jQuery('.search-btn').hasClass('fa-search')){
        jQuery('.search-open').fadeIn(500);
    } else {
        jQuery('.search-open').fadeOut(500);
    }
});
```

Comment: How are you hiding the element?

Comment: css - display: none;

Comment: Let me check the spec, MDN says inputs with the hidden attribute cannot be auto-focused, but doesn't not mention `display: none`.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything in the HTML specification to validate the `autofocus` behavior exhibited by Chrome. Here's an excerpt from the spec on this behavior.

From [4.10.19.7 Autofocusing a form control: the autofocus attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#autofocusing-a-form-control:-the-autofocus-attribute):

> When an element with the autofocus attribute specified is inserted into a document, user agents should run the following steps:
>
> [...]
>
> **Note:** This handles the automatic focusing during document load.

It doesn't mention anything about applying this behavior when the display state changes (as Chrome is apparently doing), only when the element is first inserted into the DOM. This actually appears to a be a bug in Chrome as Firefox is following the HTML spec.

Instead of using the `autofocus` attribute, you will have to trigger the focus through JavaScript.

Comment: how come it works fine in chrome? even though it is hidden initially? it's just firefox that is having the issue

Comment: css - display: none;

Comment: @AlexMurray I've updated the answer. It appears this behavior is actually a Chrome bug.

Answer (score -2):

You could use JavaScript to automatically focus into any elements with `autofocus='yes'`

```
$('[autofocus="yes"], [autofocus="autofocus"], [autofocus="true"]').focus();
```

This should, theoretically target any elements that have `autofocus` set to either `true`, `yes`, or `autofocus` and focus on them.

Comment: Just use `$('[autofocus]')`, any element with this attribute should auto-focus. Shouldn't need to though, Firefox 4+ natively supports the attribute.

Comment: I've tried this but no luck. Would it have anything to do with the input being hidden until an icon is clicked for it to display?

Comment: I've added the javascript im using to display the input. is there any way to incorporate it?

Comment: If your answer is jQuery then it's probably best if you don't just refer to it as "JavaScript" as if it's vanilla. There is nothing in the JS spec that would make that code work, it's the usage of a specific library that makes that code work.

Comment: @JimboJonny I did consider editing my answer, but couldn't be arsed